# ESP8266 servo controler

Tags: wifi, servo, battery-operated, esp8266

I am building a small application, that should be able to connect over wifi to server, pull some data and turn a connected servo accord the result. The system should be powered on battery. Is this something ESP8266 WiFi module is capable of doing? I found [this article](http://www.roboremo.com/esp8266-servo.html), but I am confused, why is the module connected to the computer, is it just for programming purposes?

Thank you,
Martin.

Comment: Yes, the ESP8266 can connect to WiFi and communicate with a server, as well as drive a PWM signal. You will probably want the variant with the IO pins broken out, the version shown in that article is not very capable.

Comment: The ESP8266 contains a processor which is capable of running custom programs, either targeting it specifically or written with a port of the Arduino environment.  It can also be used as a communications peripheral for another processor.

Comment: Check your power requirements: an ESP8266 is quite power-hungry.

Comment: The answer is definitely **yes**, to deal with the power-hungry problem raised by @wouter-van-ooijen you can look for variant that is capable to go into deep sleep mode (the ones that have GPIO16 exposed). For me, te most interesting part to use the ESP8266 in such project is the possibility to program in high level language like [Lua](https://www.lua.org). Have a look at how you can go into deep sleep mode with [NodeMCU firmware for example](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/node/#nodedsleep).